# Can one install LyX without LaTeX?

Tags: lyx, installing, texlive, collaboration

I wish to collaborate with a LyX file, using the "track changes" functionality. The collaborator doesn't have LyX or TeX installed.

They are using Mac OS X, and don't have room for the 2.3 GB MacTex package (presumably it inflates to even larger than that). Is it possible for them to install LyX and use all the basic functionality (with the exception of exporting via TeX into other formats)?

Comment: I don't believe one can use LaTeX without a TeX distribution (the common ones that go with LyX are TeXLive and MikTeX). If you and your collaborators are willing to forego the WYSIWYM functionality, you can try [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com), which is an online LaTeX editor (i.e. no local installation required). You and your collaborators can all work on the same document at the same time, and version control functionality is available at a price.

Comment: You can use LyX without LaTeX. You just won't be able to compile to PDF, which I think your collaborator is OK with. I can tell you how to do this on Ubuntu, but I don't know on MacOS how it works.

Comment: @KevinC Yes, I wasn't really interested in them using TeX per se, just as long as they could view my document in LyX, and edit it (via track changes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LyX without LaTeX. You just won't be able to compile to PDF, which I think your collaborator is OK with.

Comment: Maybe a non LaTeX collaborator will be OK with this, but if they cannot see regularly (every hour or so) that the file is still compilable and check the output, it could be a pain for you debug that file. You cannot imagine how skilled they are  to make stupid things  like paste a a table or a float inside a section title, or populate the bibliography with zero witdh spaces when you are using pdflatex, or or any other unforeseen thing.  Lyx is foolproof but do not underestimate the power of fools.